# How to automatically wrap text to new responses from a form in a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I had a working Google Spreadsheet where when new responses were filled in on the form, they would automatically get textwrapped on the Form Responses sheet.

Now recently I had to remake this spreadsheet and I just can't seem to figure out how to do that, automatically that is.

I know about 'paint format' and the textwrap button itself but I need it to do that automatically so I don't have to keep manually doing it myself.

I read about QUERY and ARRAYFORMULA but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found to do this is with a script.

Step 1: Go to Tools > Script Editor and put the following code there:

```
function wrap(e) {
  e.range.setWrap(true);
}
```

Step 2: Still in Script Editor, go to Resources > Current project's triggers, and select from dropdowns "wrap", "From spreadsheet", "On form submit".

NOTE: If under Resources you have no current project triggers - create a new one - name it "wrap" - then proceed to choose "From Spreadsheet", "On Form Submit" and it will work as stated.

Step 3: You're done. Close the Script Editor. The new form submissions will be automatically wrapped in the spreadsheet.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: This no longer works.

Answer (score 1):

With updated AppScripts (DEC 7 2020 version)

Step 1: Go to Tools > Script Editor and put the following code there:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  range.setWrap(true);
}
```

Step 2: Still in Script Editor, go to Edit > Current project's triggers, and + Add Trigger, "onEdit", "Head", "From spreadsheet", On open, > Save.

Step 3: You're done. Close the Script Editor. The new form submissions will be automatically wrapped in the spreadsheet.

Comment: This no longer works.

Comment: @brooklynsweb updated, thank you!

Answer (score -1):

@jparagon 's December 2020 edit worked, but I had to set the trigger to be "onEdit", "Head", "From spreadsheet", "On form submit" (instead of "On open") in order for it to automatically wrap text upon a new submission to the form.
Additionally, at the end of Step 1 in the answer above, you have to save your script in the Editor tab before it will allow you to do anything in Step 2 in the Triggers tab.